# Change ownership of folders created by PHP

Tags: php, apache, vps

I've just bought a VPS for testing purposes trying to learn how to use it etc.

I've setup apache/php and running a script which PHP creates folders. Ive tried setting the script to chmod it to 0755 but it still doesn't let me delete the folder.

I can't chown/chgrp as im not running the script as root.

I just need to be able to delete the folder with PHP, Is there a config file i can change so PHP creates folders with a different user group?

Thanks

Comment: set a group sticky bit on the root folder

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191039/when-could-or-should-i-use-chmod-gs-on-a-file-or-directory

Comment: how do you want to delete the folder ? can you give us some code?

Comment: the php is just a basic rmdir, But it can't remove it as the user im running doesn't have permission as the folder isnt owned by that username. I don't quite understand the group sticky :S

Comment: I assume there are 2 users ? Your user and www-data ? @Exoon

Comment: i just have my username and then root.

Comment: Who is Apache / php running as?

Answer (score 0):

Your folder is created by your script, that usually runs with the apache or web user. So you can't manipulate it as yourself (in an FTP for example).

What you can do is change the mode within your script (still running as apache or web user) like so:

```
<?php
chmod("/somedir/somefile", 0777);  // octal; correct value of mode
?>
```

Comment: This works for PHP to be able to delete it, but i still can't delete it from FTP, Any other ideas?

Comment: Sorry, meant to be: 0777